# Jetpack Compose - Make Image scale to the available size in Column/Row

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Consider the following image:

[image]

I have a `Column` that has an `Image` together with another `Column` that has some `Text` elements. What I'm trying to do is to have the `Image` scale uniformly to the available space. I just can't make it work.

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.Cyan)
        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
) {
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.rocket_boy),
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
    )
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        repeat(20) {
            Text(text = "${it}")
        }
    }
}
```

One of the things that I tried was setting the size of the `Image` to `fillMaxSize` and the `weight` of the second `Column` to `1f`, but it didn't do anything. Maybe I need to have the size of the second `Column` fixed? Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You haven't used `Modifier.weight` on the correct child. It should be applied to the view, which you need to fill the rest of the parent.

> The parent will divide the vertical space remaining after measuring unweighted child elements and distribute it according to this weight.

`Modifier.weight` has argument `fill` with default parameter `true`. This default parameter works same as `Modifier.fillMaxHeight()` (in case of `Column`), if you don't need to fill all height available, you can specify `false`:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.Cyan)
        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
) {
    val painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_redo)
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, fill = false)
            .aspectRatio(painter.intrinsicSize.width / painter.intrinsicSize.height)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        painter = painter,
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
    )
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        repeat(20) {
            Text(text = "${it}")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right about the `weight` modifier. But it is still not enough. Using just that will not scale my image. Adding a `fillMaxSize` over will push the `Text` elements to the bottom.  Adding an `aspectRatio` modifier (width / height) still the same result. In the meantime I made it work using  a `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: @daniyelp `weight` will take all available height (with the default `fill` parameter set to `true`). You can add `fillMaxWidth` if you need to scale width too. What do you mean by "push the Text elements to the bottom"? [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGqIT.png) is output of my code after adding `fillMaxWidth` to `Image`

Comment: In your output, the image seems to take all  the remaining space on top and bottom. I want the `verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly` of the first `Column` to apply to both `Image` and the `Text` elements. Try to display 5 `Text` elements instead of 20 and you'll probably see what I mean by those being pushed to the bottom. Look at pictures from my answer to see how I wanted the correct result to look like.

Comment: @daniyelp you can specify `fill = false` for `weight`, in this case it won't fill available height. See updated answer

Comment: The image remains small! regardless of how many `Text` elements are being displayed. (Sorry for the late reply)

Comment: @daniyelp maybe setting `contentScale` to `ContentScale.Crop` will solve this?

Comment: With that the image is always at maxed width. If there are too many `Text` elements, it will be cropped on top and bottom.

Comment: @daniyelp I guess that aspect ratio in this case is requited. But it'd work with `weight`, no `ConstraintLayout` needed, I've updated my answer, the code should work now as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to your image size is less than the screen max width, for that reason the container of the image fill the width, but the image remains small, if you fill the height on the image it scales correctly but the image container fills all space leaving below the list. You could try setting and aspect ratio to the modifier to prevent container from filling all available space:

```
...
val painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_dismiss_24)
Image(
  modifier = Modifier
                .aspectRatio(ratio = painter.intrinsicSize.height / 
  painter.intrinsicSize.width)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight(),
  painter = painter,
  contentDescription = null,
  contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
)
...
```

[image: result]

Comment: I think someone sent you a suggestion to swap height and width places. But still, the `aspectRatio` modifier wasn't enough.. If I add more `Text` elements, they will be pushed out of the screen. The `Image` will not scale down. In the meantime I made it work using a `ConstraintLayout` (see my answer).  Just couldn't get it work with a `Column`. But you can think of how to fix it in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider the height of the parent `Column` - as the sum of the heights of the `Image` and the nested `Column` - it can be argued that the height of your `Image` should be equal to the remainder of the height, after subtracting from the height of the parent `Column` - the height of the nested `Column`.

```
var textInColumnSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
var globalColumnSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
val imageHeight: Dp =
    LocalDensity.current.run { (globalColumnSize.height - 
    textInColumnSize.height).toDp() }

Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
            globalColumnSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
        }
        .background(Color.Cyan)
        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
) {

    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(imageHeight),
        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.rocket_boy),
        contentDescription = null,
    )
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                textInColumnSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
            },
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        repeat(10) {
            Text(text = "$it")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get it work right using a `Column`, but I succeeded using a `ConstraintLayout` and Nestor's help with the `aspectRatio`.

```
ConstraintLayout(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    val (button, text) = createRefs()

    val painter = painterResource(R.drawable.rocket_boy)
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .aspectRatio(ratio = painter.intrinsicSize.width /
                    painter.intrinsicSize.height)
            .padding(16.dp)
            .constrainAs(text) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                bottom.linkTo(button.top)
                height = Dimension.preferredWrapContent
                width = Dimension.preferredWrapContent
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
            },
        painter = painter,
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
    )

    Column(Modifier.constrainAs(button) {
        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom, margin = 16.dp)
        top.linkTo(text.bottom)
        start.linkTo(parent.start)
        end.linkTo(parent.end)
        height = Dimension.wrapContent
    }) {
        repeat(5) {
            Text(text = "$it")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

But if someone thinks that it can still be done with a `Column` instead of a `ConstraintLayout`, he can post an answer and I may accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(350.dp), // you can set this to whatever size you want your image to be
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.android_superhero1),
        contentDescription = null
    )
    Column {
        repeat(20) {
            Text(text = it.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

### This is with `350.dp` (`.size(350.dp)`):

[image]

### This is with `150.dp` (`.size(150.dp)`):

[image]